# Offer A to V sentence question

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article, to-infinitive

> - The restaurant offers customers to choose spicy level.

> - The restaurant offers customer choice of spicy level

I think second sentence is right grammatically..but the first one also make sense?

Comment: The first one does not make sense, and neither is idiomatic. _The restaurant offers customers_ (or _the customer) the choice_... or _allows customers to choose..._, and _spicy level_ doesn't sound right either.

Comment: The restaurant offers customers a choice of spiciness.

Answer (score 1):

The term "spicy level" is not normally used in English for the degree of spice in a dish. One might express this as

> - The level of spice
> - How spicy the dish is
> - the level of spiciness.
> - How much spice
>   *How hot the dish is

and in various other ways as well

Thew phrases:

> - The restaurant offers customers to choose
> - The restaurant offers customer choice of

are also not usual or natural ways of expressing this concept. A fluent speaker would probably understand either, but would think it odd.

More natural alternatives would include:

> - The restaurant allows customers to choose
> - The restaurant offers customers **a** choice of

When "*choice*" is a noun, it needs an article in constructions like this one.

So the complete sentence might be expressed as one of:

> - The restaurant allows customers to choose how spicy the dish will be.
> - The restaurant allows customers to choose the level of spice to be used
> - The restaurant allows customers to choose the level of spiciness in the dish
> - The restaurant offers customers a choice of the degree of spice.
> - The restaurant offers customers a choice of the level of spiciness.
> - The restaurant offers customers a choice of  how hot the food will be.

Other variations are also possible.

---

Oh and the word is not "*gramally*". It is properly spelled "*grammatically*"

Comment: @Lambie Thank you, correction made, now spiciness